# Powershell start IE on remote machine with specific URL

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

Is there a way to start IE on a remote machine pointing it to a specific URL using powershell.

This script will only open on my local machine:

```
$PC = Read-Host "Name of machine to run cookie creator on"
$URL = "http://www.google.co.uk"
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate($URL)
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

When you use PowerShell remoting, it creates a session on the remote computer which cannot be interacted with and has no UI. So while you *can* start the IE process, the UI will never be visible to any user.

Comment: But I can start the process, so if i started the iexplore process it would be visable to the user?

Comment: No it won't . Think about it this way. You logon to a computer, then switch account and log on with a different user. IE may be running on one, but the other user is not seeing it. Two different sessions!